# How to configure a specific application in PHP LDAP ADMIN?

Tags: ldap

I have this OU Application and I want to integrate the user provisioning using PHP LDAP ADMIN with proper authentication

Answer (score 0):

[phpLDAPadmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a generic LDAP server administration tool. If you want to dedicate it to the user provisioning for a specific application, you would write one or more [templates](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Templates) for managing the application users, and then [disable phpLDAPadmin's default template](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Config:appearance:disable_default_template) so that only your pre-defined template(s) can be used.

Authentication is mostly a matter of configuring your LDAP server with proper user accounts and access control so that the server requires authentication and allows the right people to manipulate the right objects. The exact way you do this depends on which LDAP server you're using phpLDAPadmin with. In other words, read the documentation of your actual LDAP server for instructions on that.

Since phpLDAPadmin is a PHP-based web application, you can also restrict access to the application itself with any HTTP(s) authentication mechanisms that are available on the webserver the phpLDAPadmin is installed on.

But if you only protect phpLDAPadmin and leave the actual LDAP server with wide-open permissions, anyone who can connect to the LDAP server with their own LDAP client will be able to do anything at all. It's better to do most of the access control in the actual LDAP server. You'll still want to protect phpLDAPadmin so that it is not accessible from the internet by just anyone, to block outsiders from attempting to exploit any security weaknesses in it.